# How to convert SQL Server date into C# DateTime

Tags: c#, sql-server, date, datetime, type-conversion

I'm calling a stored procedure (using SQL Server 2012) in my C# app and converting the results into a c# object. The object has a `datetime` property, and the stored procedure returns a date as one of its columns. The object `datetime` property is always `01/01/0001 00:00:00` when parsing the query result.

Here's my code to consume the stored procedure, the object used to parse the results, and the actual stored procedure itself

```
public IEnumerable<InvoicingReportDto> GetInvoivingReportPerUser(DateTime startdate, DateTime enddate)
{
    string sproc = "[Updater].[InvoicingReportPerUser] @STARTDATE, @ENDDATE";

    var result = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<InvoicingReportDto>
        (
            sproc,
            new SqlParameter("@STARTDATE", startdate.Date),
            new SqlParameter("@ENDDATE", enddate.Date)
        );

    return result.ToList();
}

public class InvoicingReportDto
{
    public DateTime LastUpdate { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    // other properties omitted
}
```

SQL Server stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Updater].[InvoicingReportPerUser]
    @STARTDATE DATETIME,
    @ENDATE DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        CAST(LastUpdate as DATE) AS LastUpdateDate,
        UpdatedBy,
        SUM(CASE WHEN CompanyStatusID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [NoStatus],
        SUM(CASE WHEN CompanyStatusID = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Complete,
        SUM(CASE WHEN CompanyStatusID = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [CeasedTrading],
        SUM(CASE WHEN CompanyStatusID = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [NoInterested],
        SUM(CASE WHEN CompanyStatusID = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Wrongnumber],
        SUM(CASE WHEN CompanyStatusID = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [FirstCall],
        SUM(CASE WHEN CompanyStatusID = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [SecondCall],
        SUM(CASE WHEN CompanyStatusID = 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [ThirdCall],
        SUM(CASE WHEN CompanyStatusID = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Research],
        SUM(CASE WHEN CompanyStatusID = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [EmailRequired],
        SUM(CASE WHEN CompanyStatusID = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Liquidation],
        SUM(CASE WHEN CompanyStatusID = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Receivership],
        SUM(CASE WHEN CompanyStatusID = 13 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [NotListed]
    FROM 
        Table
    JOIN 
        Updater.CompanyStatus CS ON CS.ID = CompanyStatusID
    WHERE 
        LastUpdate BETWEEN CAST(@STARTDATE AS DATE) AND CAST(@ENDATE AS DATE)
    GROUP BY 
        CAST(LastUpdate as DATE), UpdatedBy
    ORDER BY 
        CAST(LastUpdate as DATE)
END
```

I would expect my Dto object to have its `LastUpdate` property set to reflect the date returned from the stored procedure, but it's always 01/01/0001

Comment: Can you update your post to show us the stored procedure (not just the body of the SQL code)?  Do you get the results you want if you take that SQL code, prefix it with a DECLARE and initialization of the two parameters and run it in SSMS?

Comment: Yes I get the expected results when doing that

Comment: What was the fix?

Comment: The column returned from the stored procedure is called `LastUpdateDate` (by means of the column alias), while your DTO object expects it to be called `LastUpdate` --> as long as they don't match, this won't work .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, it isn't necessary to create procedure to just run your query.
You could define your query in some string variable in code, so you have everything centrlized in your code and use it together with `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDatareader`:

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(/* args */))
{
    using(SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand())
    {
        com.Connection = conn;
        com.CommandText = /*your query goes here */ ;
        conn.Open();
        using(SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // read your result here and manipulate them
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doh!! yes you're exactly right. My bad. Thanks for spotting that.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) your entity attribute names need to match the name of the columns. Yours don't appear to (LastUpdate vs LastUpdateDate). You need to either change the name of your property:

```
public class InvoicingReportDto
{
    public DateTime LastUpdateDate { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    // other properties omitted
}
```

or change the column alias

`CAST(LastUpdate as DATE) as LastUpdate,`

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct except you did not run your stored procedure. You should write `EXEC` to run your stored procedure:

```
string sproc = "EXEC [Updater].[InvoicingReportPerUser] @STARTDATE, @ENDDATE";
```

And double check what returns the following code at SQL Server Management Studio:

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE date = '2018-12-19', @ENDDATE date = '2018-12-11'
exec [Updater].[InvoicingReportPerUser] @STARTDATE, @ENDDATE
```

In addition, change your property `LastUpdate` of `InvoicingReportDto` to:

```
public DateTime LastUpdateDate { get; set; }
```